# Spark SQL - Pivot and concatenation

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks

I am working with spark sql and have a requirement to pivot and concatenate the data.
My input data looks like

| ID | Quantity | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | US |
| 2 | 20 | UK |
| 2 | 5 | CA |
| 2 | 20 | US |
| 3 | 15 | US |
| 3 | 20 | CA |
| 4 | 25 | US |
| 4 | 10 | CA |

My Output needs to be able to sum the quantity on ID and store the location with comma separated values.

| ID | Quantity | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | US |
| 2 | 45 | UK,CA,US |
| 3 | 35 | US,CA |
| 4 | 35 | US,CA |

I tried various methods in spark sql and pyspark available here, but was not able to achieve my results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql version below if data are in table, using `collect_list` with `concat_ws`...

```
%sql
with table1 as (
  select 1 as id, 10 as quantity, 'US' as location union all 
  select 2, 20, 'UK' union all
  select 2, 5, 'CA' union all
  select 2, 20, 'US' union all
  select 3, 15, 'US' union all
  select 3, 20, 'CA' union all
  select 4, 25, 'US' union all
  select 4, 10, 'CA'
)
select 
 id, 
 sum(quantity) as quantity, 
 concat_ws(',', collect_list(location)) as location
from table1
group by id
order by id
```

| id | quantity | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | US |
| 2 | 45 | CA,UK,US |
| 3 | 35 | US,CA |
| 4 | 35 | US,CA |